# Meteor subscriptions are not stopping after changing Ionic views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I'm using [Angular-Meteor](http://angular-meteor.com) with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com).

Meteor version: `1.3.2.4`, Angular version: `1.5.5`, Ionic version: `1.2.4`.

I'm also using ES2015 for my Meteor/Angular app.

For one view I have:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { SomeCollection } from 'path/to/collection';

import './view1.html';

class View1 {
  constructor($scope, $reactive, $state) {
    this.$state = $state;

    this.$scope = $scope;

    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.subscribe('my.subscription');

    this.helpers({
      list: () => {
        return SomeCollection.find({});
      }
    });
  }
}

export default angular.module('view1', [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  View1
]).config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider.state('app.view1', {
    url: '/view1',
    template: '<view-1></view-1>',
    views: {
      'appContent': {
        controller: View1,
        controllerAs: 'view1',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And the other view I have a similar type of setup, except I'm subscribing to a different publication.

Something like:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { SomeOtherCollection } from 'path/to/other/collection';

import './view2.html';

class View2 {
  constructor($scope, $reactive, $state) {
    this.$state = $state;

    this.$scope = $scope;

    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.subscribe('my.other.subscription');

    this.helpers({
      list: () => {
        return SomeOtherCollection.find({});
      }
    });
  }
}

export default angular.module('view2', [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  View2
]).config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider.state('app.view2', {
    url: '/view2',
    template: '<view-2></view-2>',
    views: {
      'appContent': {
        controller: View2,
        controllerAs: 'view2',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/other/template.html'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

When I switch between my Ionic views I'm noticing that I'm still polling from subscriptions from previous views. According to documentation, if I use `$scope`, the `stop()` function should be automagically called.

However, I can see using [Mongol](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol) that my subscriptions are not being stopped from switching views.

I've currently been able to use a quick fix but it's ugly and forces to populate my code with workarounds I believe should not be necessary, i.e doing:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', () => {
  this.subscriptions = [];
  this.subscriptions.push(this.subscribe('some.collection'));
  this.subscriptions.push(this.subscribe('some.other.collection'));
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', () => {
  for (var sub in this.subscriptions) {
    this.subscriptions[sub].stop();
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly stop subscriptions when switching between Ionic views?

Comment: i think your "workarounds" are actually the proper pattern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic caches controllers/views by default, so my scope was not being destroyed and therefor the `stop()` function wasn't being called when switching between views.

To fix this I simply set `cache: false` on the `$stateProvider` and this solved my issue.

However, I do think I like that my views are being cached so I think I'll figure out a nice way to stop subscriptions when switching between views but keeping `cache: true`... Any elegant ideas are welcome.